# WSO2 DataService JSON and NULL VALUE

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

When I use the native JSON message builder for a dataservice.

It translates null values into for example "mobileNumber":**{"@nil":"true"}**

Is there a way to have the output as "mobileNumber":**null** ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this requirement will be available in the DSS 3.2.2 release. The [JIRA](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-15046) is created for this issue and it is fixed in the gson message builder and formatter. The DSS 3.2.2 is not released yet. Please find the tentative date for that release from [here](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/DS?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project%3Aversions-panel)